# Optimizing Semi-prime Factoring Algo

Tags: python, optimization, sieve-of-eratosthenes, factorization

My method below is super duper crude and super duper slow. Any tips on suggestions on optimization. I know for a semi-prime of two different primes the the numbers are less or equal to half the semi-prime. But im not sure how to go about checking the list of primes more efficiently for large numbers. For n 13 digits and bigger is when mine falls apart.

```
import math
def eratosthenes(n):
    multiples = set()
    primes = set()
    for i in range(2, n+1):
        if i not in multiples:
            if i <= math.ceil(math.sqrt(n)+10):
                primes.add(i)
                    for j in range(i*i, n+1, i):
                        multiples.add(j)
    result = []
    for p in primes:
        while n % p == 0:  # while p divide n...
            result.append(p)
            n = n // p
        if n <= 1:
            break
```

Comment: Apart for an indentation error and a missing `return result` line, you functions gives expected results. You could ask on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for a thorough review. As an immediate improvement, you should take the `sqrt(n)` out of the loop to execute it only once. And if you want to use the function multiple times, you could cache the Eratosthene's sieve.

Comment: How big is _n_? Different sizes of _n_ will require different algorithms.

Comment: N is 5983391455009 or bigger

Comment: You should check out the post by @primo on [semi-prime factorization](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9088/52987).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For larger primes you can try with simple to implement [Pollard's rho algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm)

```
from fractions import gcd

def pollardfactor(n):
    a=2
    b=2
    d=1
    for c in  [1,-1,2,3,5,7,-3,-5,-7]:
        while True:
            a=(a*a+c)%n
            b=(b*b+c)%n
            b=(b*b+c)%n
            d=gcd(abs(a-b),n)
            if 1 < d < n:
                return(d)
            elif d==n :
                break
    return -1

print(pollardfactor(5983391455009))
```

This should work for 20 digits numbers in reasonable time.

Comment: So this one returns the smallest of the two primes, how do i get the second?

Comment: Try with division